# SQL Server 2008 doesn't use backup device path when running powershell script from prompt

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sqldmo

I made a script that backups all of the databases of my remote server. When I run the script from the PowerShell ISE interface, the path that I determine in the backup device works fine, but when I run it from the prompt, the path I set is ignored, and the backup is made to SQL Server's default backup directory. Why is that, and how can I fix it?
Below is my script:

```
$DestSqlTpb = "E:\BackupBD\SQL-TPB-01\";
$PastaRede = "\\sql-tpb1-01\BackupBD\SQL-TPB-01\";
Write-Output ("Started DELETE at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));    
$ComandoDeleteRede = $PastaRede + "*"
remove-item $ComandoDeleteRede
$ComandoSqlTpbLocal = $DestSqlTpb + "*"
remove-item $ComandoSqlTpbLocal
Write-Output ("Finished DELETE at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));    
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo');            
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc');            
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO');
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended');  
$Server = "SQL-TPB1-01\SQL2008";     # SQL Server Instance.    
$srv = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $Server

Write-Output ("Started SQL-TPB1-01 at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));
$dbs = $srv.Databases
foreach ($db in $dbs) 
{
  if (($db.Name -ne "tempdb") -and (!$db.IsDatabaseSnapshot)) #We don't want to backup the tempdb database 
  {
    $timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss;
    $backup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup");            
    $backup.Action = "Database";            
    $backup.Database = $db.Name;            
    $backup.Devices.AddDevice($Dest + $db.Name + "_full_" + $timestamp + ".bak", "File");            
    $backup.BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of " + $db.Name + " " + $timestamp;            
    $backup.Incremental = 0;     
    $backup.CompressionOption = 1;
    # Starting full backup process.            
    $backup.SqlBackup($srv);     
    # For db with recovery mode <> simple: Log backup.            
    If ($db.RecoveryModel -ne 3)            
    {            
        $timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss;            
        $backup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup");            
        $backup.Action = "Log";            
        $backup.Database = $db.Name;            
        $backup.Devices.AddDevice($Dest + $db.Name + "_log_" + $timestamp + ".trn", "File");            
        $backup.BackupSetDescription = "Log backup of " + $db.Name + " " + $timestamp;            
        #Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.            
        $backup.LogTruncation = "Truncate";
        # Starting log backup process            
        $backup.SqlBackup($srv);    
    };
  };
};
Write-Output ("Finished SQL-TPB1-01 at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));
Write-Output ("Started COPY at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));    
copy-item $ComandoDeleteRede $DestSqlTpb
Write-Output ("Finished COPY at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));
```

When I just Run from ISE, it goes well, but if I save the ps1 file, and execute from prompt, the path in the device is ignored. Tks

Comment: any final and full source code script working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting the problem is with this line:

```
$backup.Devices.AddDevice($Dest + $db.Name + "_full_" + $timestamp + ".bak", "File");
```

You are using the $Dest variable, which is not defined anywhere in your script. I bet that you have the $Dest variable set to the path you want in the ISE session, which is why it's working there.

But in a new console window, $Dest is null so SQL is using the default path.